# Ne explétif avec jusqu'à

Tags: ne-explétif

Sur le nouvel obs, il est écrit que le ne explétif peut être utilisé "après certaines conjonctions comme *avant que* et *à moins que*".

Je voulais savoir si cette utilisation était limitée à ces conjonctions ou si une phrase telle que "*Je continuerai jusqu'à ce que je ne lâche prise*" était correcte ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'après l'[article](http://bescherelle.ca/le-ne-expletif/) suivant, qui est l'essentiel en ce qui concerne l'usage, il n'est pas possible d'écrire cette phrase.

- Le verbe de la principale est à la forme positive mais ce  n'est pas un verbe de crainte ou de peur.
- Le verbe de la principale n'exprime pas l'évitement, ni l'empêchement, ni la défense, ni la précaution.
- La construction de la principale ne consiste pas en une comparaison.
- La locution conjonctive « jusqu'à ce que » ne semble  pas faire partie du lot de celles qui peuvent justifier l'usage du « ne explétif ». Il y a en plus de   quatre locutions souvent considérées (avant que, à moins que, depuis que¹, sans que² ([réf.](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/observations/ne.htm)) les locutions suivantes que l'on conçoit en tant qu'assimilables aux verbes de crainte dans la principale.
- de peur que, de crainte que,

¹<sub>Seulement dans la langue ancienne (semble même ambigüe à mon avis)</sub>
²<sub>Contestée ou simplement rejetée par certains grammairiens</sub>

Je ne trouve pas dans la littérature du sujet d'explication qui regroupe ces  locutions conjonctives sous un principe unificateur. Je conçois cependant que toutes ces locutions, sauf « sans que » émettent la possibilité d'une alternative potentielle, soit par le biais d'un terme explicite, soit par le biais d'un sentiment. C'est d'ailleurs ce qui semble détacher « sans que » des autres : on ne lit pas dans cette locution en combinaison avec « ne » l'expression d'une alternative ou éventualité mais celle d'une condition, ce qui expliquerait son exclusion  par un nombre non négligeable de grammairiens de celles qui sont compatibles avec le « ne explétif ».  On ne  trouve pas dans  « jusqu'à ce que » cette idée d'éventualité non plus et on y perçoit seulement une idée de finalité ; ceci me fait penser que cette dernière locution ne répond pas au critère justifiant un « ne » explétif.

On doit distinguer une différence, il me semble entre les deux formes suivantes, bien qu'il soit dit assez souvent que la particule ne sert à rien. C'est en tout cas un exemple qui permet de mieux voir l'idée unifiante qui semble justifier la discrimination que j'ai faite en ce qui concerne « sans que » et « jusqu'à ce que ».

- Il faut lui rapporter son vase avant qu'il ne vienne le chercher. (*Il n'y a pas d'action convenue quant à venir chercher le vase ou non mais ne pas le rendre disponible en temps voulu a de fortes chances de causer l'action de se réaliser, d'en faire une alternative, une éventualité.*)
- Il faut lui rapporter son vase avant qu'il vienne le chercher. (*Il existe l'action convenue ou prévisible indépendamment et « avant que » ne fournit plus que l'idée d'une limite et non, comme avec le concours de la particule, d'une éventualité.*)

On trouve que dans les livres « jusqu'à ce que [je/tu/…/ils] ne » est très souvent suivi par « plus », ce qui entraine que la particule est négative. On trouve quelques cas dans la vieille langue où la particule pourrait être explétive, à moins qu'elle soit ambigüe, et au moins un cas récent (2014) mais cela me semble difficilement pouvoir confirmer un usage.

(1809 — Le nouveau Robinson: pour servir à l'amusement et à ..) Quels que soient les travaux que vous entrepreniez, il suffit que vous ayez assez de résolution pour ne pas les abandonner jusqu'à ce que vous ne les ayez conduits à leur fin.

(2014 — La fraternité royale (Tome 2) - Escorte de charme)
— Il était votre ami jusqu'à ce que vous ne lui voliez son épouse.
 — Je ne la lui ai pas volée, soupira-t-il. Votre père n'était pas tellement porté sur tout ce qui plaisait à votre mère.